# Python replication of an Ncloth and nucleus in Maya

Tags: python, maya

Can someone please complete this code?

```
# create a cloth node
mesh = cmds.ls(sl=True)[0]
nCloth = cmds.createNode("nCloth")
nucleus = cmds.createNode("nucleus")

# connect time node 
cmds.connectAttr("time1.outTime", nCloth + ".currentTime")

# connect your mesh to the ncloth 
cmds.connectAttr(mesh + ".worldMesh", nCloth + ".inputMesh")

# create an output shape that will be the simulation mesh
outMesh = cmds.createNode("mesh", parent=mesh, name='outmesh')
cmds.connectAttr(nCloth + ".outputMesh", outMesh + ".inMesh")

# connect the startframe
cmds.connectAttr(nucleus + ".startFrame", nCloth + ".startFrame")

# Connect the cloth node to the nucleus with an available ID
cmds.connectAttr(nCloth + ".currentState", nucleus +".inputActive[{}]".format(index), f=1)
cmds.connectAttr(nCloth + ".startState", nucleus + ".inputActiveStart[{}]", f=1)

# force the refresh when used in batch
cmds.getAttr(cloth + ".forceDynamics")
```

There are still many errors, and honestly, I don't know what I'm doing. for now, I'm getting

```
name 'index' is not defined
```

Idk what's that intended. And although a Ncloth and nucleus were already applied, it just gave me a weird mesh with missing parts of the material attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to lear the basics of python, it takes a day and you will save a lot of time searching for simple errors. Your problem is that you use the variable `index`in this line:

```
cmds.connectAttr(nCloth + ".currentState", nucleus +".inputActive[{}]".format(index), f=1)
```

And this name is not defined anywhere in your code. Before you use any variable, you must define it e.g.

```
index = 0
```